# Difference in user endpoints

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-edu

In my Azure AD tenant, I have few users which I get using `https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/users` and I get Education users for a school using `https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/education/schools/<id>/users` or `https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/education/users`

What is the difference here and how do we differentiate them in the portal panel? 
Can we make a general user an education user under a specific school?
I actually am not an admin on the portal.

Answer (score 1):

At the AAD level (which is what you're surfacing in the Azure Portal), there isn't a difference between the objects.

What is different is how the `User` resource is rendered. When you query Users via `/education/users`, you get some additional metadata. For example, if the User is a Student you will get the [`educationStudent`](http://%20https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/educationstudent?view=graph-rest-1.0) properties. If they're a Teacher, you'll see the [`educationTeacher`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/educationteacher?view=graph-rest-1.0) properties.

The [`educationUser`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/educationuser?view=graph-rest-1.0) resources also have additional navigation properties for [`educationClass`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/educationclass?view=graph-rest-1.0) and [`educationScool`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/educationschool?view=graph-rest-1.0).  For example, you can call `v1.0/education/users/{id}/classes` but not `v1.0/users/{id}/classes` because the standard `User` resource lacks the `classes` navigational property.

This same model carries over to other areas:

- `educationUser` extends the `user` resource
- `educationClass` extends the `group` resource
- `educationSchool` extends the `administrativeUnit` resource

You can [add an educationUser to an educationSchool](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/educationschool-post-users?view=graph-rest-1.0) like this:

```
POST https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/education/schools/{schoolId}/users/$ref
Content-type: application/json
{
  "@odata.id":"https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/education/users/{userId}"
}
```

As an aside, I strongly caution against using the `/beta` version. The Beta version can *and will* break from time to time. Breaking changes happen without warning and, as such, is simply not reliable enough to use in a production application.

Comment: I understand this. but https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/users ----- https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/education/schools/<id>/users ---- https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/education/users. But why the set of users in first URL and other 2 URLs are different? I don't get the users I see in the first URL in other 2? This is the issue. How to manage it from admin panel?

Comment: You can't manage an Administrative Unit (AU) from the Portal today. As for the difference in results, when you call `/schools/{id}/users` you're scoping the results to a single AU. Users that are not members, or are members of a different school would therefore not show up in the results.

Comment: My problem is I can see some users not having PrimaryRole or they are not under any school (A). Other users are there under school properly (B). But from the Portal I can see all above users and I want to know how to differentiate or make the users part of a school with primary role.

Comment: Admin Units are just a way of organizing objects. Users don't have to be a member of one so it isn't surprising that you'd see some users attached to an AU while others are not. If you create a user in the Portal for example, it won't be a member of an AU (aka School) .